# Is there any penalty for getting a miss (False Positive) in Bit.Trip Core?

Tags: bit-trip-core

The principle gameplay of Core involves firing a quad-directional laser by pressing a direction and a button simultaneously. If you hit a beat, it gets cleared, you get score, etc.

It is also possible to shoot the laser when there *aren't* beats in that direction, which will cause "Miss" to appear. Does getting a miss in this instance (when there are no beats to hit, rather than *actually* "Miss"-ing a beat) have any effect on your combo, counter, or affect SUPER mode?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If I remember correctly this will just break your chain. It won't affect your mode meters or combos.

Comment: Whoa! Thanks, Chris, and welcome to our website! If you don't mind a minor followup - what do you mean by chain (as opposed to combo)?

Comment: Sure man, glad to help out. I think when you hit consecutive beats it creates a "chain" after maybe 10 hits or so? That's when the "+10" etc text shows up after you hit a beat. I think chains add a flat bonus to the score increase you get after each hit. If you shoot and don't hit anything, it breaks your chain. As for "combos" I think I meant to say "multipliers". Which each mode you go up (HYPER, MEGA, SUPER), you get a multiplier to your score. These are tied directly to what mode you are in, so firing on nothing won't affect them. Hope that helps!